# how to write to a given index-pattern in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana

I have a dotnet core project set up for Elasticsearch, Kibana and Logstash. Right now I just spit out random data to the log, but the thing is, that when I run the app then it automaticly runs on the same index-pattern under '_index' in the "Discover-section" in Kibana.

The question is - how in my code - do I define which index-pattern I want to connect to? I presume it is inside Program.cs inside main, but I am not sure how.

I want to be able to decide myself inside the app-code, which index-pattern I want to log to, if that makes sense.

Currently using serilog sinks. Is it in that direction, that I should fix it or am I looking in the wrong direction?

**Update** (trying to implement code from link given by mike b)

```
            var connectionSettings =
            new ConnectionSettings()
                .DefaultIndex("defaultindex")
                .DefaultMappingFor<Project>(m => m.IndexName("mycustomindex"));
        var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
        var searchResponse = elasticClient.Search<Project>();
```

Also I have created an index inside kibana, which will show, when I enter "GET _cat/indices", but when running the project and seeing that logs are received by kibana I still see that they are registered under the same old index ("httplog") as seen in the snippet below:

[image: snippet of log]

how do I change that - or what am I doing wrong?

PS: I can see the created index inside "Discover" / drop down menu, but it is empty for logs. Instead my httplog-index is filled with logs...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the .NET Elasticsearch client, it'll infer the name it thinks you want for an index. You can override that behavior or specify index names for specific index actions.

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index-name-inference.html

Comment: thanks! It sure looks like that I need to go in that direction, but when trying it out, I still get "httplog-%{hostname}-2019.09.03" under _index... Even when trying all the options specified in the link... Actually I can't find my changes anywhere in the log.

Comment: I think we'll need to see more code. The snippet you included in the update sets up a client for a search request, but what does your real code look like that posts the logs to Elasticsearch? There should be a call to `.Index()` or `.IndexMany()`

Comment: Then I'm confused. I've tried all the options given in the link, you've provided, but none of them work. You are saying that I'm doing a search request - is that the problem? My logs do show on kibana, now I just want them to be indexed the right way. So basically all the other things work except placing them in custom indices.

Comment: I suspect - from what you write - that I'm looking the wrong way and maybe should be looking at the .conf-file, where input, filter and output are defined?

Comment: Yes, if logstash is what's shipping logs into Elasticsearch and not your app, then the logstash config is where you need to specify the desired index name. See the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.3/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index